# appium installation error for android , java

Tags: appium

1. ffmpeg is needed to record screen features. Please read https://www.ffmpeg.org/ to install it
2. bundletool.jar is used to handle Android App Bundle. Please read http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-appbundle/ to install it. Also consider adding the ".jar" extension into your PATHEXT environment variable in order to fix the problem for Windows
   WARN AppiumDoctor
3. gst-launch-1.0.exe and gst-inspect-1.0.exe are used to stream the screen of the device under test. Please read https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-screen-streaming/ to install them and for more details

just cant understand how to go further , have installed and set the paths still  same errors

Downloaded and set every the set the path, still the same errors .